# Google Cloud Directory Sync java nullpointer exception

Tags: active-directory, ldap, java, g-suite, google

I'm trying to do some testing with Google Cloud Directory Sync and Active Directory, but whatever I do, I always get nullpointer exeptions. As far as I can find GCDS is a Java application. The GCDS installer installs a version of the Java run-time environment in a sub-folder so it shouldn't be a issue that the wrong version of java is installed or something like that?

When I try to open a configfile:

[image: nullpointer1]

All my checks are OK:

[image: checksareok]

But when I try to simulate a sync, I also get nullpointer exceptions:

```
[2022-03-23 15:31:09,941+0100] [AWT-EventQueue-0] [INFO] [general.syncdialog.SyncDialog] Starting simulation
[2022-03-23 15:31:09,941+0100] [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-8] [ERROR] [sync.agent.FullSyncAgent] Caught Throwable during full synchronization. This exception caused the sync to fail. For full context, search the logs to see where it happened first. Details: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.usersyncapp.plugin.ldap.schemasConfig.CustomSchemasConfigXmlMapper.getSchemasDefinitions(CustomSchemasConfigXmlMapper.java:233)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.plugin.ldap.schemasConfig.CustomSchemasConfigXmlMapper.toCustomSchemasConfig(CustomSchemasConfigXmlMapper.java:224)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.plugin.ldap.config.loaders.SourceLdapConfigLoader.loadCustomSchemas(SourceLdapConfigLoader.java:1893)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.plugin.ldap.config.loaders.SourceLdapConfigLoader.doCollections(SourceLdapConfigLoader.java:130)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.plugin.ldap.config.loaders.LdapConfigLoader.loadFromElement(LdapConfigLoader.java:615)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.plugin.ldap.config.loaders.LdapConfigLoader.load(LdapConfigLoader.java:112)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.plugin.ldap.LDAPPlugin.setConfiguration(LDAPPlugin.java:339)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.sync.PluginFactory.initializePlugin(PluginFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.sync.PluginFactory.initializeFromPluginConfigList(PluginFactory.java:130)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.sync.PluginFactory.initializePluginsIntoGroup(PluginFactory.java:159)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.sync.agent.FullSyncAgent.loadPlugins(FullSyncAgent.java:457)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.sync.agent.FullSyncAgent.initializeRun(FullSyncAgent.java:360)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.sync.agent.FullSyncAgent.call(FullSyncAgent.java:130)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.ui.page.general.AbstractSimulateSyncWorker.doInBackground(AbstractSimulateSyncWorker.java:85)
    at com.google.usersyncapp.ui.page.general.AbstractSimulateSyncWorker.doInBackground(AbstractSimulateSyncWorker.java:28)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm obviously missing something here, but I have no clue what... The Active Directory is a Windows 2016 and there are no more logfiles than the ones I already found which I copied above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a version problem. I was using version 4.7.14
(February 8, 2022) and had those problems, but when installing 4.7.2 (downloadable from here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pq08SS1wiGllVAUMpKaqfFRQLSkFJfhc) I didn't have those problems anymore...